# How is this equation derived?

Tags: functions, function-and-relation-composition

The equation in question:

$$f^{[s]}(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\binom sn\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{s-n}{s-k}\binom nk(-1)^{n-k}f^{[k]}(x)$$

where $f^{[s]}(x)$ is the $s$th iteration of $f(x)$.

This formula is mentioned [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/17605/how-to-solve-ffx-cosx/44727#44727) along with "some other formulas that give the same result."

But this formula, to me, just seems so arbitrary and I would like to know how it's derived, and I would also like to know about these "other formulas." The linked post mentions "expressing its superfunction in a form of Newton series," and I have no idea what a Newton series is, and I don't even have a decent understanding of what a superfunction is.

Comment: The first question is if it is correct at least in some context. The formula of the linked post looks like an interpolation between the $f^{[k]},k \in \mathbb{N}$ made to mimic the properties of the fractional derivatives of polynomials.

Comment: @reuns well I wouldn't know...

Comment: Hmm, the Newton-interpolation is long known, I met it first in L. Comtet's book on "Advanced Combinatorics". However, the following formula (which you cite) seems completely out-of-the-blue for me, and I do not know why that (engaged!) user anixx doesn't have a repository anywhere where he shows his derivations from one to the other formula... Coming across this problem often with this user I've given up to try to find that derivations on my own and to assume I could use that formulae at all.